# Why is this the output of the below c code 12?

Tags: c, return-value, function-call

> This is a simple c program but the output is 12
> I am not understanding how the same output is 12.please explain

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int show() 
    {
        printf("hello world\n");
    }
    int main() 
    {
        int i;
        i=show();
        printf("%d",i);
      
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `show` needs to return something. Not returning a value from a function that is defined to return something is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Please write the following sentence 1000 times: Don't ignore compiler warnings

Comment: Did you intend to do: `return printf("hello world\n");` ? Because then it will print 12 (in `main`)

Comment: i have written the code as it is and notreturned anything thats why i am confused how come the ans is 12.

Comment: Beginners should always compile their programs with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`. Then fix all bugs that the compiler points out.

Answer (score 5):

If a function ends by reaching the closing `}`, and the return value is used (in the caller), it's undefined behavior.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.9.1

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You use `int show(){...}` function, which means you need to return a value of an integer type.

For example:

```
int show(){
  int num = 0;
  return num;
} // show()
```

Above the code, it returns `num` (integer).

According to your code, you return nothing at all, and then do `i=show();`,

so `i` is set by the system because you didn't return a value.